# Modifying HTML elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jquery to add and remove a class from `<li>` elements according to a variable's value ( `i` ).

Here is a jsfiddle of what I have done so far http://jsfiddle.net/LX8yM/

Clicking the "+" increments `i` by 1 ( I have checked this with chrome's javascript console ).

One should be able to click "+" and the class `.active` should be removed from and added to the `<li>` elements accordingly.

...I can get the first `<li>` element to accept the class, that's all...

Comment: All your code does is increment i. The if statements are run once when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for if statements:

```
$(document).ready(function (){   
  $('#add').click(function (){
    $('.numbers .active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJk4m/)

Do note that I added an 'active' class to first list item. You could always do this via JS if you do not have control over the markup.

Comment: Very smart. This would be the better solution if you have a list of items.

Comment: @Nick +1 Thats why I love SO, where people offer optimized solution :)

Comment: Nice solution, could I use the same idea to decrement `i` and thus reverse the process? maybe `.prev()`?

Comment: @proPhet: Yes, allthough the start-`active` class should be placed in the last element for it to work

Answer (score 3):

Your if..else.. is hanging in `document.ready`.  Wrap the increment inside a function and call it respectively.

Like

```
$(document).ready(function (){      
    //variable
    var i = 1;

    //if statments
    function incre(i){ // wrap into a function and process it
    if(i == 1){
        $('#one').addClass('active');
        $('#two').removeClass('active');
        $('#three').removeClass('active');
    }else if(i == 2){
        $('#one').removeClass('active');
        $('#two').addClass('active');
        $('#three').removeClass('active');
    }else if(i == 3){
        $('#one').removeClass('active');
        $('#two').removeClass('active');
        $('#three').addClass('active');
    }
    }

    //change i
    $('#add').click(function (){
        incre(i++);  // pass it as a parameter
    });

});
```

[**Working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LX8yM/9/)

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0; // set the first value
    $('#something').click(function(){
    i++; // every click this gets one higher.

    // First remove class, wherever it is:
    $('.classname').removeClass('classname');
        // Now add where you need it
        if( i==1){
        $('#one').addClass('classname');
        } else if( i==2){
        $('#two').addClass('classname');
        } else if( i==3){
        $('#three').addClass('classname');
        }
    }):
});
```

Comment: If you check his code, his if.. else code is hanging in `document.ready`

Comment: @Martijn will your answer add the class when document loaded you gave the minus mark to me huh....

Comment: No it wont. But he never asked for that. Also, the default-active shouldn't be loaded via javascript. If you have a slow connection, the 'active' class will be loaded after some content is being shown, and the class 'active' might make an change to the layout, which can make it hop.

Answer (score 0):

See this code. Initially you have to add class to **one**.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    //variable
    var i = 1;
    $('#one').addClass('active');

    //if statments


    //change i
    $('#add').click(function (){
        i++;
        if(i == 1){
        $('#one').addClass('active');
        $('#two').removeClass('active');
        $('#three').removeClass('active');
    }else if(i == 2){
        $('#one').removeClass('active');
        $('#two').addClass('active');
        $('#three').removeClass('active');
    }else if(i == 3){
        $('#one').removeClass('active');
        $('#two').removeClass('active');
        $('#three').addClass('active');
    }
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's being called only once, not in the click event function. This edit of your fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/LX8yM/2/

put it in the

```
'$('#add').click(function (){}'
```